# Modal Pop-up Image Viewer for Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, modal-popup, image-viewer

I am looking for a control which can show me selected image detail view which is actually gonna be bigger image in a modal pop up to show a better view of image to my customers. You know those standard modal pop-up resizeable to selected image original size. Dynamicly resizable modal pop-up is actually what I am looking for and of course it should be for Asp.net (if possible for 3.5)

I've searching for a while but I haven't been able to come up with a acceptable solution yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not asp.net, but rather javascript based, Lightbox is the granddaddy of displaying a popup with a larger image. http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

There are many other similar open-source client-side 'controls' that would do what you want.

You may also need to roll your own from jQuery of YUI to build the resizeable requirement that you want.

Comment: You know what, that is great. I can use that in my asp.net project. Thanks. It seems easy to implement in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at Telerik:
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx

The have some controls that would probably get the job done.
Otherwise search for Infragistics, they have similar controls.

Comment: But they're not free . I want free of charge controls because I am not that much rich :)